# I have a Gaussian Pulse in time domain. How can I get a specific frequency band of this signal, in time domain? in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, fft, frequency-analysis

I did fft() on my signal, and now I have the signal in frequency domain. But, I want to pick a frequency band and then plot the signal in time domain again. 
How can I do that? 
should I extract that band from the frequency domain? 
Then convert it back to the time domain? 
How can I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify your question and maybe include a piece of code with sample signal. Do you want to discard (set to zero) all the frequencies outside of the specific frequency band?

Comment: BTW, take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074760/how-to-change-value-of-a-signals-range-in-matlab/44076172#44076172

Comment: You can extract your frequency band of interest by multiplying your fft result with a mask. Since any real valued time signal has a conjugated complex frequency spectrum you will need to make sure you apply your masking (or ideal filter) to both sides of the spectrum. For example, if you have a time signal with a samples and you are interested in the higher frequent portion of the spectrum your mask could look for example like [1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1]. You can transform the multiplication result back into the time domain. If you are getting a complex results, the masking was not done correctly.

Comment: Essentially, what you are looking for is band filtering in signal processing. For a quick solution (that resembles a box filter), refer the comment above by @MichaelC. If you have a background in signal processing and want to learn how to do it in MATLAB, see [this](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/fourier-analysis-and-filtering.html) page. You should give more context and samples when you ask a question, by the way.